# Strings not going into the right txt file [discord.py]

Tags: python-3.5, discord.py

I've got this code, basically what it's supposed to do is log a specific users messages when a person with the role 'ADMIN' or 'semi-mod' say '!log user'. The code puts the messages into a .txt file who's name is the id of the user being logged. If it doesn't find a txt file with the users unique ID, it creates a new one. However my problem is that if I log more than one person, messages will go into the other users text file etc.

````
@commands.command(pass_context=True)
    async def log(self, ctx, user: discord.Member):
        if 'Administrator' or 'semi-mod' in [x.name for x in ctx.message.author.roles]:
            users2log.append(user.id)
            msg = """```
Member's Message Being Logged
{} messages are now being logged at the request of {}.
```""".format(ctx.message.mentions[0], ctx.message.author)
            await self.bot.send_message(discord.Object(id='320289509281628165'), msg)
            await self.bot.add_reaction(ctx.message, '\U00002611')


-----------------------
Part not working:
-----------------------


    async def on_message(self, message):
        if message.author.id in users2log:
            for user in users2log:
                try:
                    f = open(user, 'a')
                    msg = """
User: {}
Time: {}
Message: {}
\n""".format(message.author, time.localtime(), message.content)
                    f.write(msg)
                    f.close()
                except FileNotFoundError:
                    os.system("touch " + user)
````

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The messages get added to other user's files because you loop through the entire `users2log` array and append to each file even though you only want to log the message to one single user's file. It should work if you remove the for loop in `on_message` so you only append to the file matching the user's id:

```
async def on_message(self, message):
    if message.author.id in users2log:
        user = message.author.id
        try:
            f = open(user, 'a')
            msg = """
User: {}
Time: {}
Message: {}
\n""".format(message.author, time.localtime(), message.content)
            f.write(msg)
            f.close()
        except FileNotFoundError:
            os.system("touch " + user)
```